# How to use serde_json with a union type like enum?

Tags: rust, serde, serde-json

I have two structs that I want to serialize/deserialize with the tag as a `"type"` field in JSON, like so.

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[serde(tag = "type")]
struct ThingA {
    value: usize,
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[serde(tag = "type")]
struct ThingB {
    value: usize,
}
```

These serialize as expected. For example,

```rust
let a = ThingA { value: 0 };
println!("{}", serde_json::to_string(&a)?);
// This yields the expected result:
// {"type":"ThingA","value":0}
```

However, I'm running into trouble when I try to add an enum to stand in as a union type for the structs.

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[serde(tag = "type")]
enum Thing {
    ThingA(ThingA),
    ThingB(ThingB),
}
```

The definition above works fine for deserializing JSON, but adds an extra field during serialization.

```rust
let json = r#"{"type": "ThingB", "value": 0}"#;
let thing: Thing = serde_json::from_str(json)?;
// Correctly parses to:
// ThingB(ThingB { value: 0 })

println!("{}", serde_json::to_string(&thing)?);
// Incorrectly serializes with an extra "type" field:
// {"type":"ThingB","type":"ThingB","value":0}
```

Changing `#[serde(tag = "type")]` to `#[serde(untagged)]` on the `Thing` enum causes the opposite problem: `Thing` instances serialize properly, but don't get parsed correctly anymore.

My goal is to get JSON `{"type": "ThingB", value: 0}` to evaluate to `Thing::ThingB(ThingB {value: 0})` during deserialization, and vice versa, but only if I'm deserializing to a `Thing`. If I have an unwrapped `ThingB`, like `ThingB {value: 0}`, I want it to serialize to `{"type": "ThingB", value: 0}` as well.

So my questions are: Is there any way to assign the serde `tag` or `untagged` attributes such that they only apply during serialization/deserialization (similar to serde's `rename`)? If not, any advice on how to implement `Serialize` and/or `Deserialize` to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just use `tag` in your `Thing` enum, leaving the others clean:

```rust
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize}; // 1.0.124
use serde_json; // 1.0.64

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct ThingA {
    value: usize,
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct ThingB {
    value: usize,
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[serde(tag = "type")]
enum Thing {
    ThingA(ThingA),
    ThingB(ThingB),
}

fn main() {
    let json = r#"{"type": "ThingB", "value": 0}"#;
    let thing: Thing = serde_json::from_str(json).unwrap();
    println!("{}", serde_json::to_string(&thing).unwrap());

}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=85c55fce1e68d4f63ac3f800634d695f)

As requested in the comments.
In case we would want to have both tagged (enum and structs) we would need to make some `serde` abracadabra playing with wrappers and with the `with`. More info can be found [here](https://serde.rs/remote-derive.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem is, I want a `ThingA` not wrapped in the `Thing` enum to also have a `"type": "ThingA"` when serialized to JSON.

Comment: @danwoz then probably you would need another wrapper that uses tagging for when they are single used instead of with the enum.

Comment: Or implement a foreign serialized version.

Comment: Ah, the wrapper idea is interesting. What's a foreign serialized version? Would that be implementing `Serialize`/`Deserialize` manually?

Comment: @danwoz, it would be a combination of different things. A wrapper type + serialize with to add the internal tagging. Check some of the things you would need [here](https://serde.rs/remote-derive.html)

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to accept this answer, but could you add some of the info from your comments into the answer for future readers?